# How can i send input data from form fields on my website to a discord webhook which pms a user on discord?

Tags: javascript, php, discord, webhooks, discord.js

[ideal look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLLNB.png)

Webook would dm user specific info inputted into the form on my website:

name, age, location.

Answer (score 0):

Discord Web hooks can be used to send messages to servers but it can not be used for direct  messaging users. You can read more about discord web hooks [here](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks)

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks can't send messages in direct messages or groups. But they can send in a discord server.

However, if you want to send a message to a user in their DMs, you can create a simple bot for that.